# How to get a deleted element in a contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I set the root div to `contenteditable`, and it contains many `img` and `video` elements. So when a user edits it and presses backspace to delete one element, How can I get which one the user deleted and get the deleted element's attributes values?

Comment: Share what you have tried,or post your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re interested in the deleted element and its properties, one way is to set a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to track modifications to the DOM. Its callback provides changes and affected elements and other userful information.

```
(new MutationObserver(function(mutations){
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation){
        if(mutation.type=='attributes')
            console.log('Element attributes may have changed, see record:',mutation);
        else
        if(mutation.type=='childList')
            console.log('Child nodes were modified, see record:',mutation,
                        'or removedNodes:',mutation.removedNodes);
});})).observe(document.getElementById('edit'),{
    subtree:true,
    attributes:true,
    childList:true,
    characterData:true,
    characterDataOldValue:true
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0tdm1wwv/2/

Take a look at it in other browsers too, since `contenteditable` has some interesting flavors.

Comment: I was just thinking what if I get the element before the current cursor, but how? :)

Comment: Interesting approch Dakab, I am trying to test this on Chrome with Jsfiddle url but its not working for me.

Comment: @user4878054: A `MutationObserver` provides information on DOM changes (“mutations”). You’ll see which elements were removed and what their properties were, but cursor position is a subject on its own.

Answer (score 0):

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input

Register an eventlistener for the event `input`. If you need IE support you might consider using `keypress` event instead.

The events might fire before the actual change happend, and `keypress` might not register *paste* and *cut* changes, so you want to handle those events as well (`input` fires on those too).

Then calculate the difference before and after the edit, analyse it and there you go.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/814j80z2/

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var myContent = {
                currentList: [], //List since last time.
                initialList: [], //Starting list, just if we need it at some point.

                //Storing all current nested elements in currentList and initialList
                Init: function(){
                    var tRoot = document.getElementById('Contenteditable');
                    var tL = document.querySelectorAll('a, img'); //Or just all '*'.

                    for(var i=0, j=tL.length; i<j; i++){
                        this.currentList.push(tL[i]);
                        this.initialList.push(tL[i]);
                    }

                    if (!tRoot.oninput) tRoot.oninput = function(){myContent.onInput(this)} //Depending on your requirements use others.
                    if (!tRoot.onkeyup) tRoot.onkeyup = function(){myContent.onInput(this)} //Depending on your requirements use others.
                },

                //Comparing current nested elements with currentList and set new currentList
                checkChangedElements: function(e){
                    if (e){
                        var tE = []; //Storing the exceptions.
                        var tN = []; //Our new current list.
                        var tC = []; //Current elements:

                        var tL = document.querySelectorAll('a, img'); //Or just all '*'.
                        for(var i=0, j=tL.length; i<j; i++) tC.push(tL[i]);

                        for(var i=0, j=myContent.currentList.length; i<j; i++){
                            //if (tC.some(function(item){return item === myContent.currentList[i]}) tE.push(tL[i])
                            if (tC.indexOf(myContent.currentList[i]) === -1) tE.push(myContent.currentList[i])
                            else tN.push(myContent.currentList[i])
                        }

                        myContent.currentList = tN;
                        return tE;
                    }
                },

                //Our input function firing each two seconds
                onInput: function(e){
                    if (e){
                        if (e.inputTimer) clearTimeout(e.inputTimer); //We fire it after two seconds without any input
                        e.inputTimer = setTimeout(function(e){
                            var tL = myContent.checkChangedElements(e);
                            e.inputTimer = null;
                            console.log('Deleted elements: ', tL)
                        }.bind(undefined, e), 2000)
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload = 'myContent.Init()'>
        <div contenteditable = 'true' id = 'Contenteditable'>
            <img alt = '' src = 'https://www.google.com//images/srpr/logo11w.png' />
            <a href = 'https://www.google.com/'>Google</a>
            <img alt = '' src = 'https://www.google.com//images/srpr/logo11w.png' />
            <a href = 'https://www.google.com/'>Google</a>
            <img alt = '' src = 'https://www.google.com//images/srpr/logo11w.png' />
            <a href = 'https://www.google.com/'>Google</a>
            <img alt = '' src = 'https://www.google.com//images/srpr/logo11w.png' />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Edit: Added onkeydown for elder IE versions.